# Lazy load / defer images in carousel inside modal in Boostrap 4.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I’m trying to make it so my high resolution images (jpgs png gifs) that are inside of the modal carousel don’t load until the thumbnail is clicked on. Getting lazy load to work on carousels in modals seems extra tricky.

Like a newbie I assumed that functionality was built into Bootstrap 4.5. I’ve found many similar questions on here as well as other places (I can post them if anyone wants) but I can’t get any of them to work, some are outdated, unanswered, or not applicable to Bootstrap 4.5. The most promising one I’ve found is here:
https://github.com/verlok/vanilla-lazyload/issues/451

I like it because it’s vanilla js (although I’m not totally comfortable in jquery), but more importantly because it wouldn’t require me to drastically rewrite my code, the page is quite large and I’m hoping to be able to simply add a class to the images.

But regardless, this one won’t work for me either. Any advice (for a newbie)? I’ve pasted my (abbreviated) code below, and I’ve uploaded the files to github: https://github.com/epignosis567/mygithub/tree/main/lazyLoadBootstrap

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="../mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    
    
</head>

<body id="page-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <!-- Media content -->
            <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-9 p-4">

                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col p-0 text-center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 500px">
                        <img class="img-fluid pb-3 myPics" src="img/01-thumb.png" width="99%" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="0"/>
                        <img class="img-fluid pb-3 myPics" src="img/02-thumb.png" width="99%" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="1"/>
                        <img class="img-fluid pb-3 myPics" src="img/03-thumb.png" width="99%" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="2"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- begin carousel modal-->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-body p-1 ">
                        <!-- begin carousel-->
                        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" pause="false" data-ride="false" data-interval="false" >
                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                              <img class="d-block w-100 lazy" data-src="img/01-4K.png" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                              <img class="d-block w-100 lazy" data-src="img/02-4K.png" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                              <img class="d-block w-100 lazy" data-src="img/03-4K.png" />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
                        </div>      
                        <!-- end carousel-->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end carousel modal-->            

            </div>
    <!-- End media content -->                  
        </div>  
    </div>
 
<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../myscript.js"></script>
    

<!-- Lazy Load script -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-lazyload@17.3.1/dist/lazyload.min.js"></script>
    
<!-- Lazy Load script -->
<script>
    
    var carouselLazyLoad = new LazyLoad({
        elements_selector: ".lazy"
    });

    $('#carousel.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    let next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (let i=0;i<2;i++) {
        next=next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }

    // The following line tells LazyLoad that new elements have been added to the page 
    carouselLazyLoad.update(); 
    });
    
</script>


    
</body>

<script>
    //carousel script to open to the thumb that was clicked on
    $('.myPics[data-slide-to]').on('click', function(){
    $('#myModal').carousel($(this).data('slide-to'));
    });
</script>
      
</html>
```

Comment: I think I got it working! I've updated the code above and the github file if anyone can check to confirm that it's correct and works for them. The first image should defer loading its hi res modal counterpart.

Comment: I'm re-adding my comment about the carousel cycling problems. The Bootstrap 4.5 carousel does indeed seem to have it's own bugs and I've filed a ticket (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/33275). 

HOWEVER, using this lazy loading script introduces additional problems. I've updated my github file if anyone wants to try it. With carousel options `data-ride=“false” data-interval=“false” pause="false` a carousel should not advance on its own. However, when using this lazy load script an error arises when a user clicks off the browser window resulting in the carousel automatically cycling.